# Only scalars symmaries are shown in tensorboard, no graph

Tags: python, r, tensorflow, tensorboard

Everything seems ok in the code, but tensorboard is not showing any graphs, nor showing any graph or histogramms tabs, all I can see at the top is "inactive".  [Here is a screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x81cF.png) 
[image]
My code contains :

```
train_writer <- tf$summary$FileWriter(logs_path,sess$graph)
...
train_writer$add_summary(summary, epoch )
train_writer$flush()
```

Is there anything I should add to my code so as to visualize the graphs ? 
Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

In Python you simply add

```
train_writer.add_graph(tf.get_default_graph())
```

(assuming you are only working with the default graph). Something similar should work for R as well.

Comment: For R you can use train_writer$add_graph(sess$graph)  or the default graph, but the problem isn't solved even when I tried added this. It is kind of logical  since giving the sess$graph to the summary file writer (as I am doing in the code above) is equivalent to using this command. So if one doesn't work, potentially the other one won't as well.